# PHP Unit, rodar teste de banco, teste com mocks e teste com SQL Lite tudo junto

Tags: php, phpunit

É o seguinte pessoal, trabalho em um sistema enorme, tem projetos ou mini serviços dentro de um projeto que precisamos testa-los usando o Mock, ou usando banco de Dados ou o SQL Lite do PHP.

O problema é que para cada um desses tipos de testes tenho que setar configurações diferentes no PHPUnit, e eu queria rodar esses vários tipos de teste diferentes de uma vez só.

Isso seria possível, se sim alguém poderia me dar um exemplo ?

Comment: Tem gente que negativa mas não pergunta nada não questiona nada, moral da história, nem deve saber o que eu estou falando, e também nem se preocupa em saber do que realmente se trata. vai entender...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode tentar usar o método `setUp()` para configurar o ambiente necessário para realização dos testes e o método `tearDown()` para retornar o ambiente ao que era antes de você iniciar os testes. Você pode encontrar muita informação no [Capíluto 4 - Ambientes](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/pt_br/fixtures.html) do manual do PHPUnit. Quanto a rodar tudo de uma vez se seus testes estiverem no diretório `tests` por exemplo, é só você executar o comando `phpunit tests/`.

Comment: Vou da uma olhada aqui, se der certo eu volto e marco sua resposta.

Comment: Consegui mudar as configuracões usando o setUp e o tearDown, Obrigado !